# How to access the polygon vertices in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects

I am able to retrieve a list of polygons from the opened map layer in ArcGIS using the following C# code:

```c#
        IMxDocument pMxDoc;
        pMxDoc = (IMxDocument)ArcMap.Application.Document;
        IMap pMap;
        pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap;

        IFeatureLayer2 pFLayer;
        pFLayer = (IFeatureLayer2)pMap.get_Layer(0);

        // Retreve the feature class.
        IFeatureClass featureClass = pFLayer.FeatureClass;

        // Retrieve the number of polygons in the map.
        IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
        int numberOfPolygons = featureClass.FeatureCount(queryFilter);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPolygons; i++)
        {
            IFeature feature = featureClass.GetFeature(i);

            // Get polygon.
            IGeometry geometry = feature.Shape;
            IPolygon polygon = (IPolygon)geometry;
        }
```

How to access the vertices (coordinates) of the rings of those polygons?

Comment: Have a look at IPointCollection for accessing the vertices of a polygon.

Comment: I cannot find any method in ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPolygon and ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Polygon classes that return a point collection. Do you know how to do it? Besides, I need to have access to polygon vertices for every polygon ring, but I cannot find how to access the rings as well.

Comment: OK, now I am able to access the rings of a polygon using IPolygon4 polygon = feature.Shape as IPolygon4; IGeometryBag exteriorRings = polygon.ExteriorRingBag;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following c# ArcObjects code shows you how you access the individual vertices of a polygon ring.

```c#
                IPolygon4 polygon = currentFeature.Shape as IPolygon4;
                //IPolygon4.ExteriorRingBag should be used instead of IPolygon.QueryExteriorRings,
                //which does not work in .NET because of C-Style Arrays
                IGeometryBag exteriorRings = polygon.ExteriorRingBag;

                IEnumGeometry exteriorRingsEnum = exteriorRings as IEnumGeometry;
                exteriorRingsEnum.Reset();
                IRing currentExteriorRing = exteriorRingsEnum.Next() as IRing;

                //Create a point object for the Query methods
                //The point doesn't need to be created each time
                IPoint queryVertex = new PointClass();

                int counter = 1;
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ExteriorRingCount = " + polygon.ExteriorRingCount);
                while (currentExteriorRing != null)
                {
                    IPointCollection pointCollection = currentExteriorRing as IPointCollection;
                    IEnumVertex enumVertex = pointCollection.EnumVertices as IEnumVertex;
                    if (enumVertex == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("NULL enumVertex!");
                        return;
                    }
                    enumVertex.Reset();

                    int partIndex;
                    int vertexIndex;

                    //Query the next vertex - have to create the point
                    //QueryNext is faster than Next, because the method doesn't have
                    //to create the point each time
                    enumVertex.QueryNext(queryVertex, out partIndex, out vertexIndex);

                    while (queryVertex != null)
                    {
                        string report = "X, Y : " + queryVertex.X + ", " + queryVertex.Y + " - Part Index : " + partIndex + " - Vertex Index : " + vertexIndex + "\n";

                        MessageBox.Show(report);
                        enumVertex.QueryNext(queryVertex, out partIndex, out vertexIndex);
                    }
                    ...
                }
```

Comment: Answers should have words in addition to code, explaining what was done and why it works. Links to documentation are not inappropriate.

Comment: For the one who has the same problem as I had I think it will be enough to look at the code in my answer. It provides a sequence of right method calls to achieve the result. As to your point "Why it works", I find it a philosophical question.

Comment: Except they won't see it if the question is closed as non-reproducible. Understanding the philosophy of ArcObjects is critical to using it.  If you can't explain that, it's not a good answer.

Comment: This is the answer that has solution to the problem. I think calling it not good is pedantic. Surely there are ways to improve it, but still this answer is what I was looking for and contains all information needed.

Comment: It works but I think I should point out you don't need to EnumVertices from the point collection.. IPointCollection supports get_Point (index) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000286000000 to access directly from the IPointCollection. Also, although it's helpful to see the exterior/interior ring code, if you don't need to get exterior/interior rings specifically you can iterate the rings from IGeometryCollection. Still, it works so it's worth a +1.

Answer (score 0):

This C# code snippet allow you to loop over every vertices. Source: [ArcObjects Library Reference (Geometry) IPolygon4.ExteriorRingBag Property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ExteriorRingBag_Property/002m000002n0000000/)

```
    public static void PolygonToString(IPolygon4 polygon)
    {
        IGeometryBag exteriorRingGeometryBag = polygon.ExteriorRingBag;
        IGeometryCollection exteriorRingGeometryCollection = exteriorRingGeometryBag as IGeometryCollection;
        Console.WriteLine("polygon.ExteriorRingCount = " + exteriorRingGeometryCollection.GeometryCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < exteriorRingGeometryCollection.GeometryCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("polygon.ExteriorRing[" + i + "]");
            IGeometry exteriorRingGeometry = exteriorRingGeometryCollection.get_Geometry(i);
            IPointCollection exteriorRingPointCollection = exteriorRingGeometry as IPointCollection;
            for (int j = 0; j < exteriorRingPointCollection.PointCount; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Point[" + j + "] = " + PointToString(exteriorRingPointCollection.get_Point(j)));
            }
            IGeometryBag interiorRingGeometryBag = polygon.get_InteriorRingBag(exteriorRingGeometry as IRing);
            IGeometryCollection interiorRingGeometryCollection = interiorRingGeometryBag as IGeometryCollection;
            Console.WriteLine("polygon.InteriorRingCount[exteriorRing" + i + "] = " + interiorRingGeometryCollection.GeometryCount);
            for (int k = 0; k < interiorRingGeometryCollection.GeometryCount; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("polygon.InteriorRing[" + k + "]");
                IGeometry interiorRingGeometry = interiorRingGeometryCollection.get_Geometry(k);
                IPointCollection interiorRingPointCollection = interiorRingGeometry as IPointCollection;
                for (int m = 0; m < interiorRingPointCollection.PointCount; m++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Point[" + m + "] = " + PointToString(interiorRingPointCollection.get_Point(m)));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static string PointToString(IPoint point)
    {
        return (point.X + ", " + point.Y + ", " + point.Z);
    }
```